# How to identify the source of a text selection event coming from a CompareEditorInput in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, event-handling, diff, subclipse, eclipse-pde

In my eclipse plugin I have the following code:

```
public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute( ExecutionEvent event ) throws ExecutionException {
        ISelection sel = HandlerUtil
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked( event )
            .getSelectionService()
            .getSelection();

        if( sel instanceof TextSelection ) {
            IEditorPart activeEditor = PlatformUI
                    .getWorkbench()
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                    .getActivePage()
                    .getActiveEditor();
            IEditorInput editorInput = activeEditor.getEditorInput();

            if( editorInput instanceof CompareEditorInput ) {
                // here are two possible sources of the text selection, the
                // left or the right side of the compare editor.

                // How can I find out, which side it is from?
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here I'm handling a text selection event coming from an `CompareEditorInput`, i.e. the result of comparing two remote revisions of a file with subclipse.

Now I want to handle the text selection properly. For that I have to know if it selects some text inside the left side editor or inside the right side editor.

How can I find that out?

**EDIT 2010-04-10:**

The concrete instance of `CompareEditorInput` is `org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.compare.SVNCompareEditorInput`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is: `org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput` (which have its [java sources here](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/compare/CompareEditorInput.java.htm)) is an **abstract class** which has not always "left" or "right" pane:

```
/**
 * The most important part of this implementation is the setup 
 *  of the compare/merge UI.
 * The UI uses a simple browser metaphor to present compare results.
 * The top half of the layout shows the structural compare results 
 *  (e.g. added, deleted, and changed files),
 * The bottom half the content compare results  
 *  (e.g. textual differences between two files).
 * A selection in the top pane is fed to the bottom pane. 
 * If a content viewer is registered for the type of the selected object, 
 *  this viewer is installed in the pane.
 * In addition if a structure viewer is registered for the selection type,
 *  the top pane is split horizontally to make room for another pane 
 *  and the structure viewer is installed in it. 
 * When comparing Java files this second structure viewer would show 
 *  the structural differences within a Java file, 
 *  e.g. added, deleted or changed methods and fields.
 */
```

The question is: do you know the exact implementation type of this `CompareEditorInput` object?

I.e: It is interesting to see how concrete classes deal with selection:
The [`org.eclipse.compare.internal.ResourceCompareInput`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/compare/internal/ResourceCompareInput.java.htm#ixzz0kgD4HdUo) for instance deals with [`org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/IStructuredSelection.java.htm), and comes with an [utility function to get left and right `IResource` based on the selection](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/compare/internal/Utilities.java.htm#ixzz0kgDZ0TTl).